# How to use "currentTime" property for MpMoviePlayerController

Tags: time, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to use the property of MPMoviePlayerController i.e "currentTime". But its showing warning "warning: 'MPMoviePlayerController' may not respond to '-currentTime' ". Can you please help me for how to use this property.

Actually i am trying to find out the duration of time for played video . So that i will check with timer ( NSTimer ) and than calculate how much time the played video is played or seek forward . And next time while i am playing the same video so i will start from the last spot time and play from that time when i resumed .

Thanks,
KamalBhr.

Answer (score 0):

You would not see **currentTime** as part of **MPMoviePlayerController** thats a part of **AVPlayer**.